# Linux QT - how to determine if GPU is used instead of CPU to draw screen

Tags: c++, linux, qt, graphics, arm

I have existing C++ project on TI OMAP5: QT + QNX (very Linux-like) + ARM.

One application that's running is a GPS + 2D map.
Whenever the car/arrow needs to be updated, I record a "large"-ish CPU spike. I'm a total newbie in {ARM, QT} but I still suspect something is not optimal. Even if the *just* arrow itself changes orientation, the CPU usage spikes.

I suspect that the GPU is not being used - fully or at all - to accelerate the drawing (though of course the CPU spike could be due to bad software design like a database read/write everytime this update happens).

I need to determine which is the case.

**QUESTION**

1. How can I profile the GPU to determine whether it's being used (and to what extent) during this operation?
2. By inspecting the QT code, is it possible to *definitively* determine whether the GPU vs CPU is used? Like are there certain QT widget classes that are guaranteed to use the GPU **or** do I have to call other functions to map them onto the GPU?

Comment: TL;DR: Qt doesn't magically use the GPU unless you ask it to.